# DateTimePicker and Datatransformer, the form render doesnt take the string into account

Tags: symfony, bootstrap-datetimepicker, data-transform

I got somme issue with Symfony to convert a DateTime into string. I use a DataTransformer to format my Datetime but in the form, there is an error that say : "This value should be of type string".

Here is my code:
My Entity : Shift.php (only the necessary)

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Assert\DateTime(message="La date de début doit être au format DateTime")
 */
private $start_at;
```

My ShiftType :

```php
$builder
    ->add('start_at', TextType::class, ['attr' => [ 'class' => 'dateTimePicker']])
    ->add('end_at', TextType::class, ['attr' => [ 'class' => 'dateTimePicker']])
    ->add('has_eat')
    ->add('break_duration')
    ->add('comment')
    ;
$builder->get('start_at')->addModelTransformer($this->transformer);
$builder->get('end_at')->addModelTransformer($this->transformer);
```

And my DataTransformer :

```php
/**
 * @param DateTime|null $datetime
 * @return string
 */
public function transform($datetime)
{
    if ($datetime === null) 
    {
        return '';
    }
    return $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i');
}
/**
 * @param string $dateString
 * @return Datetime|null
 */
public function reverseTransform($dateString)
{
    if (!$dateString) 
    {
        throw new TransformationFailedException('Pas de date(string) passé');
        return;
    }
    $date = \Datetime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $dateString);
    if($date === false){
        throw new TransformationFailedException("Le format n'est pas le bon (fonction reverseTransform)" . "$dateString");
    }
    return $date;
}
```

As i said, when i want submit the form, there are errors with the form.
It said "This value should be of type string." and it's caused by :

```
Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation {#1107 ▼
  root: Symfony\Component\Form\Form {#678 …}
  path: "data.start_at"
  value: DateTime @1578465000 {#745 ▶}
}
```

Something weard, when i want to edit a shift, Symfony get the date from the db and transform it into string with no error message. But as i want to save the edit, i got the same issue

Could you help me please ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue in the past when using $this-> inside a form.

Sometimes $this would not contains the current data. It might explain why it loads at first, but, on submit, it might not be filled properly.

I would suggest creating a custom form type for better reusability, and I know it works very well.

Since you already have your DataTransformer class, you would need to create a new custom form Type. This new form type will extend TextType and use the datatransformer.

For example:

```
namespace App\Form\Branch\Type;

use App\Form\Branch\DataTransformer\PhoneFormatTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PhoneType extends AbstractType
{
    private $tools;


    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $transformer = new PhoneFormatTransformer();
        $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array());
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return TextType::class;
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'phone';
    }
}
```

If you services are not autowired, you would need to add a service definition with a specific tag

```
App\Form\Branch\Type\PhoneType:
    tags:
    - { name: form.type, alias: phone }
```

All that is left to do is use your new form type in your form builder:

```
use App\Form\Branch\Type\PhoneType;
...
$builder
->add('phone', PhoneType::class);
```

It is a tad more work, but it makes it very easy to reuse, which no doubt, you will have to do everytime a datetime field is needed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I tried tour solution and i wil use it, but it was not the solution to my issue. With your code, i got the same error.

The solution was in the Entity. In the annotations of start_at, I did an @Assert/DateTime and it was a bad use of it. I just delete this line and all is now correct :

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * 
 */
private $start_at;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\GreaterThan(propertyPath="start_at", message="La date de fin doit être ultérieure...")
 */
private $end_at;
```

However, i use your code because it's a lot reusable so thank you for your contribution